# Weighted Average with ElasticSearch

Tags: javascript, math, elasticsearch, stat

I'm new to ElasticSearch and i'm trying to make an weighted average in my index.

My data looks like this:

```
data = [{"id": 344,"q28": 1},{"id": 344,"q28": 1},{"id": 344,"q28": 2}, ...]
```

"q28": can be equal to 1,2,3 or 4

Example in JavaScript:

```
var data = [{"id": 344,"q28": 1},{"id": 344,"q28": 1},{"id": 344,"q28": 2}]
function calcWeightAverage(res) {
    var score = 0
    for (var i in res) {
        if (res[i].q28 == 1)
            score += 100
        else if (res[i].q28 == 2)
            score += 50
        else if (res[i].q28 == 3)
            score += 25
        else if (res[i].q28 == 4)
            score += 0
    }
    return score / res.length 
}

console.log(calcWeightAverage(data)) // output 83.333...
```

Can you help me with to find a query that would calculate the weighted average of q28 directly in ElasticSearch ?

Thank you !

---

### UPDATE 1

I'm close, see: "https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html"

To test it, i created a file in config/scripts/my_script.groovy

```
1 + my_var
```

Then you have to restart ElasticSearch and make this query:

```
GET /_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "my_field": {
      "script": {
        "file": "my_script",
        "params": {
          "my_var": 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's working, now i have to work on the script.
How can i loop in all my data to do something like my javascript function ?

Answer (score 2):

Just to help you with a shorter Javascript part for the average.

```js
function calcWeightAverage(res) {
    return res.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r + ({ 1: 100, 2: 50, 3: 25, 4: 0 }[a.q28] || 0);
    }, 0) / res.length;
}
   
var data = [{ id: 344, q28: 1 }, { id: 344, q28: 1 }, { id: 344, q28: 2 }];

console.log(calcWeightAverage(data));
```